# Graph of symplectomorphism is symplectomorphic to the image of a closed $1$-form.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, $(T^*M, \omega_{\rm can})$ its cotangent bundle, and consider the twisted product $M\times \overline{M} = (M\times M, \omega \oplus (-\omega))$.

Consider a symplectomorphism $\varphi \in {\rm Sp}(M,\omega)$ which is $C^1$-close to the identity ${\rm Id}_M: M \to M$.

We know that:

- the diagonal $\Delta \subseteq M\times \overline{M}$ is Lagrangian;
- the graph $\Gamma_\varphi\subseteq M \times \overline{M}$ is Lagrangian;
- $M \cong 0^{T^*M} \subseteq T^*M$ is Lagrangian.

Ok. Assume that $U$ is a neighborhood of $\Delta$ in $M\times M$ which contains $\Gamma_\varphi$, $U_0$ is a neighborhood of $M \cong \Delta$ in $T^*M$, and that $F: U \to U_0$ is a symplectomorphism such that $F(x,x) = x \cong 0_x$, for all $x \in M$.

Let $L = F(\Gamma_\varphi)$.

> I want to check that there is a closed form $\sigma \in \Omega^1(M)$ $C^1$-close to the zero section such that $L = {\rm Im}\;\sigma$.

Since $F$ is a symplectomorphism, we have that $L$ is also Lagrangian, so once we find $\sigma$, it will be closed (I already have the result "${\rm Im}\,\sigma$ is Lagrangian iff ${\rm d}\sigma = 0$"). So I'd guess that it suffices to show that $L$ intersect each cotangent space to $M$ exactly once. But it is not clear to me that if $x \in M$, then $F(x,\varphi(x)) \in T_x^*M$.

The $C^1$-close to the zero section I guess it is automatic, in some sense, since $L\subseteq U_0$ (it was never made clear what exactly is meant by "$C^1$-close", although one can guess).

I'd like some help filling up these details, and to be sure nothing I said so far is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't need to be the case that $F(x,\phi(x)) \in T_x^*M$. Imagine a flat plane, and then an embedding from such said plane on a neighbourhood of the zero section of its normal bundle on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (this is just taking the plane and wiggling it around). The wiggling does not need to preserve fibers (i.e., be a vertical-only wiggling). This is an analogue to your situation here. The point is that, if such wiggling is $C^1$-close to the identity map, such an image is a section of the normal bundle nonetheless (by the inverse function theorem applied to the projection map).

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer, or is Aloizio's comment enough?

Comment: The comment is helpful, but I think that having an answer would be good (since I don't know how to work with this $C^1$-close condition)..

Comment: I had the impression that I've seen a related question to the one I'll link here before. I even left a comment! If you are still looking for an answer, the answer here may be sufficient: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3612313/59234 . @IvoTerek

Comment: @Aloizio Thanks a lot! I took a quick look at what you wrote and it is the sort of detail I expected! (I just need to sit down and digest it slowly now)