# The Arnol'd conjecture for symplectomorphisms sufficiently close to the identity

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, symplectic-geometry

In studying symplectic geometry, a relatively easy corollary of Weinstein's Lagrangian Neighbourhood theorem is the following.

> On a closed symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ with $H^1_{\text{dR}}(M)=0$, every symplectomorphism sufficiently $C^1$-close to the identity has at least $\text{Crit}(M)$ fixed points.

In the proof of this, it is claimed that if $\phi$ is sufficiently $C^1$ close to the identity, the graph of $\phi$ is contained in a given open neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of the diagonal $\{(x,x)| x\in M\}$. Why is this claim actually true?
For filling in the details, I would like to find a $C^1$ neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}$ of the identity such that if $\phi\in\mathcal{N}$, then $\text{Graph}(\phi)\subset \mathcal{U}$. Intuitively, it is very clear that for $\phi(x)$ sufficiently close to $x$, we have that $\text{Graph}(\phi)$ is contained in $\mathcal{U}$. However, how can I choose such an open neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}$ such that it actually works that the graph of each $\phi$ in this open neighbourhood is contained in $\mathcal{U}$? I know from Page 37 in Hirsch, Differential topology that the group of $C^1$ diffeomoprhisms $M\to M$ is open in $C^1(M)$, but I could not find the result in there any further.

Comment: You don't need $\phi$ to be sufficiently $C^1$ close to the identity in order for the graph of $\phi$ to be contained in a given neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of the diagonal. This can be achieved by only requiring $\phi$ to be sufficiently $C^0$ close. You need it to be $C^1$ close for another part of the argument, which is that such a graph will become a section of the cotangent bundle when you apply the Weinstein's Lagrangian Neighbourhood theorem.

Comment: Think about a one-dimensional case for visualization. (Yes, symplectic manifolds are even-dimensional, but the visualization has nothing to do with symplectic geometry.) Fixed a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of the diagonal, if $\phi$ is $C^0$-close to the identity, then the graph of $\phi$ belongs to $\mathcal{U}$ (this is almost the definition of being $C^0$-close), but when you "rotate" the image to see the diagonal as the $x$-axis, if $\varphi$ is wobbly enough, it doesn't become a function. It is the same underlying phenomenon.

Comment: I do see the similarites in this visualization that $d\phi$ should behave nicely as well. But I do want to fill in the details, so is there a specific way of choosing $\mathcal{N}$ such that it works?

Comment: What I mean is, how small should $\mathcal{N}$ be such that the image of the graph of $\Phi$ is the graph of a 1-form? I see how it works intuitively by a 1-d visualization but I don't see how to translate that into abstract differential geometry language

Comment: Every proof Always talks about sufficiently $C^1$ close, but I am just wondering what is meant with sufficiently $C^1$-close in this context, and how small "sufficiently" is. For example section 9.3 here https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf

Comment: I have been thinking of approaching this problem differently, by just defining $\mathcal{N}$ to consist of all symplectomorphisms whose graph will become a section of the cotangent bundle by applying Weinstein's aforementioned theorem. But then the trick would be to show that $\mathcal{N}$ is an open neighbourhood of the identity, and I am unsure about the details in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $g \in C^1(L;T^*L)$ is an embedding such that $\pi \circ g$ is an embedding, then the map $C^1(L;T^*L)\to C^1(L;L)$ given by $h \mapsto \pi \circ h$ takes embeddings near $g$ to embeddings. Indeed, since embeddings are open, we can take a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}_1$ of $g$ such that all of its elements are embeddings. Then, we intersect this with a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}_2$ for which the elements don't have derivative sending into the kernel of $d\pi$. (Since the set 
$$\{h : \exists x \in M, 0 \neq v  \in T_xM \text{ with } d\pi(dh(v))=0\}$$ is closed in $C^1(L; T^*L),$ this is possible. If this isn't clear, you can pick $h_n \to h$ together with chosen $x_n$ and normalized $v_n$ after some choice of metric on $L$ and use compactness of $L$ and of the unit sphere.) The image of $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{U}_1 \cap \mathcal{U}_2$ therefore consists of maps $h$ such that $\pi \circ h$ are embeddings, which must  in fact be diffeomorphisms by the inverse function theorem.

Any $h \in \mathcal{U}$ will be able to be "reparametrized" to be a section. Indeed, letting $\alpha : = (\pi \circ h)^{-1}$, we have that $h' = h \circ \alpha$ is such a reparametrization. Note that it is obviously a section, since $\pi \circ h' = \pi \circ h \circ (\pi \circ h)^{-1}=\mathrm{Id}$, which is the definition of being a section.

Now just apply all of the above to the case where $g$ is the embedding of $L$ as the zero section. Let $f:U \to U'$ be the symplectomorphism given by the Weinstein neighbourhood theorem, where $U$ is a neighbourhood of the graph $L$, which is a Lagrangian submanifold, and $U'$ is a neighbourhood of the zero section of $T^*L$. Then there is a map $f_{\#}:C^1(M;M\times M)^{U} \to C^1(L;T^*L)$ given by composition and extension. (The superscript means that we are restricting to those maps that take $M$ inside $U$.) This map is continuous, since $f$ is a diffeomorphism. So picking $\mathcal{V}$ to be $f_{\#}^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ and considering $\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$, where
\begin{align*}
\iota: C^1(M; M) &\to C^1(M;M \times M) \\
h &\mapsto \left(x \mapsto \left(x,h\left(x\right)\right)\right),
\end{align*} 
which is again continuous, you have the neighbourhood you want.

---

For the sake of completeness and future reference: in order to complete the argument to prove the Arnold conjecture in this case, note that graphs of symplectomorphisms are Lagrangian submanifolds of the product. So the image of the graph of a symplectomorphism which is in the neighbourhood constructed above will yield a Lagrangian submanifold which is the geometric realization of a section of the cotangent bundle, i.e. a one-form $\mu$.

This one-form $\mu$ is closed, since a geometric realization of a one-form is Lagrangian in the cotangent bundle if and only if the one-form is closed. (This is a well-known fact, but can be seen in page 17 [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf)) By the hypothesis of $H^1_{dR}(M)=0$, it is exact, i.e. $\mu=dk$ for some real function $k: L \to \mathbb{R}$. The critical points of $k$ are then precisely the intersections of the geometrical realization of $\mu$ with the zero section, which in turn are precisely the points for which $f_{\#}(\iota(\phi)))(x)=f_{\#}(\iota(\mathrm{Id}))(y)$, i.e., $f((x,\phi(x)))=f((y,y))$ for some $x$ and $y$. Since $f$ is bijective, we must have $(x,\phi(x))=(y,y)$, and then $x=y$ and $\phi(x)=x$. It follows that the fixed points of $\phi$ are in bijection with the critical points of $k$, thus the fixed points of a $\phi$ which is in $\iota^{-1}(\mathcal{V})$ are bounded from below by the minimum number of critical points which a smooth function in $M$ can have.

Comment: In the beginning, is $g$ itself an embedding?

Comment: @James Yes. I'll add this for clarification. (Note, however, that this is implied by the fact that $\pi \circ g$ is an embedding.)

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer, and I am about to except it apart from one small last step! Am I correct to understand that one could write $C^1(M,U)$ instead of $C^1(M;M\times M)^U$ in the last paragraph? Then am I correct in my understanding that $f_{\#}(g)=f\circ g$? Because then I don't see why $f_{\#}(g)$ is a $C^1$ map $L\to T^*L$?

Comment: @James For the first question, yes, but I thought that by putting $M \times M$ explicitly it'd avoid confusion in thinking that $U$ might be a subset of $M$. For the second question, yes too, $f_{\#}(g)= f \circ g$. Since $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ ($g$ by definition of the space and $f$ since it is a diffeomorphism), the composition also is. If the issue is that it should go to $C^1(M, T^*L)$ instead, recall that $M \simeq L$ by $x \mapsto (x,x)$. So if you wish to be more precise, you should write $f_{\#}$ as $g \mapsto f \circ g \circ i^{-1}$, where $i$ is the aforementioned identification.